# WPF - Getting Image Width/Height from internet URL

Tags: wpf, image, height, width

I've managed to get an image's width/height if its stored in my computer with the following code:(Fullpath is the file's full location)

```
        var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(FullPath), BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
        var width = bitmapFrame.PixelWidth;
        var height = bitmapFrame.PixelHeight;
```

But the second I try to change the FullPath to an internet image (such as http://www.interweb.in/attachments/pc-wallpapers/16187d1222942178-nature-wallpaper-nature-summer-wallpaper.jpg) the width and height will not determine the real values needed and will just remain with the value of "1".

I've been sitting for a few hours here trying to figure out what went wrong and working a way around it but without success. 
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. For net `Uri` the `ImageSource` will download the image asynchronously, to avoid blocking.

```
    var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(FullPath), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    if(bitmapFrame.IsDownloading)
    {
        bitmapFrame.DownloadCompleted += (e, arg) =>{
            var width = bitmapFrame.PixelWidth;
            var height = bitmapFrame.PixelHeight;

        }
    }
```

You want to wait for the `DownloadCompleted` event.

Comment: I've tried to copy your suggestion (only thing I changed was the parameter name from e to t because I'm testing it on a button click) but the values are still 1.

Comment: I've found the problem, it needs to be BitmapCreateOptions.None instead of BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation . Thank you very much :)!